# Add unique id to every row using ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, html, ag-grid

I used the ag-Grid plugin in javascript for my grid. My problem is figuring out how I can update the rows into database. How can I set a unique id to every row?

```
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 600px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // specify the columns
        var columnDefs = [
            {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
            {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
            {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
        ];

        // specify the data
        var rowData = [
            {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 'test', my_unique_id: '123'},
            {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000, my_unique_id: '42341'},
            {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000, my_unique_id: '567'}
        ];

        // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
        var gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            rowData: rowData
        };

        // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
        var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

        // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
        new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
    </script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? And is this script supposed to be inside the <div>?

Answer (score 0):

On the definition of your columns `columnDefs` you need to add the key and, if you need, set `hide: true` to this data not appears on UI

```
 var columnDefs = [
            {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
            {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
            {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}, 
            {headerName: "Key", field: "my_unique_id", hide = true}, 
 ];
```

See all properties for columns on `ag-grid` docs here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware of this, but ag-grid actually assigns a unique ID to every row, when the row data is set.

On of the ways to access the `id` for each row node would be to use the `forEachNode()` method, as specified within the [ag-grid gridOptions API documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessing-data/#accessing-row-node-api-methods). `forEachNode()` iterates all rows, and returns the data for each row.

Assuming you are using Vanilla JavaScript (without any frameworks such as React or Angular), you do the following to get the `id`

```
 gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node => {
   console.log(node.id);
   // do the rest
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
    headerName: "Num",
    field: "id",
    filter: true,
    width: 150,
    cellRendererFramework:(params)=>{
      return <span>{params.rowIndex}</span>
    }
  },
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.